# Elasticsearch 1.0 and pyelasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

Does anyone know if pyelasticsearch (currently v0.6.1) works with Elasticsearch v1.0? Has anyone tried using these together (yes, I know Elasticsearch v1.0 was just released) yet? I'm using both in a Django application and while I can't say for certain it certainly looks as though pyelasticsearch is causing the internal server error I'm currently getting. The application functioned as intended with Elasticsearch v0.90.11 and pyelasticsearch v0.6.1.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the server error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last commit I see on [pyelasticsearch](https://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch/commits/master) is from several months ago.

There are [breaking API changes from .90 to 1.0 for ES](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/breaking-changes.html), so I would guess pyelasticsearch is not going to work against it.